# Eager Loading in Entity Framework Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

Have Entity Framework Core 2.2 removed Eager Loading? The include method won't appear in Visual Studio intellisense, and when I write it manually it gives an error: "it does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extensions..."

Example

```
School school = _context.Students.Include...
```

My demo is made with a simple ASP Core 2.2. Web Application. Not much have been changed. The project use this packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Have Entity Framework Core 2.2 removed Eager Loading? The answer is No! There is something wrong in your project! Delete bin and obj and then rebuild it again. also check whether necessary packages are installed!

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I uploaded my demo project which use the School and Student example.

Comment: How do I do that? (Sorry I am no expert)

Comment: Do you mean https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Have Entity Framework Core 2.2 removed Eager Loading?

No, it still [exists](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2223).

> The include method won't appear in Visual Studio intellisense, and when I write it manually it gives an error: "it does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extensions..."

Looks like you are missing the following `using` statement in your [code](https://github.com/isak-glans/ExistingDbAndCoreLib/blob/b3beafbc732f0afec9cf053e18c923642a76d270/ExistingDbAndCoreLib/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```